# defining a `module_function` and later overriding the same method: how many methods exist?

Tags: ruby, function, class, module

**Main Question:** In the [Ruby API docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function) for the `module_function` method, I see the following code example:

```
module Mod
  def one
    "This is one"
  end
  module_function :one
end

class Cls
  include Mod
  def call_one
    one
  end
end

Mod.one     #=> "This is one"
c = Cls.new
c.call_one  #=> "This is one"

module Mod
  def one
    "This is the new one"
  end
end

Mod.one     #=> "This is one"
c.call_one  #=> "This is the new one"
```

If I'm reading this code right, I see the following:

1. A module is defined named `Mod`, along with a method named `one`.  The `module_function` method is then called, passing the name of this method as the param.
2. A class is defined named `Cls`, and the `Mod` module is included in this class, giving the class access to the method defined inside `Mod`.  Then a wrapper method is created, which just delegates its call to the module method.
3. The module method is called directly, and the wrapper method is called on a new instance of the class.  Both calls return the same thing.

After that point is where I get confused.  The module is then re-opened and a new implementation of the `one` method is created.  Then the two original method calls (the module call and the class instance call) are performed again, this time with different outputs.

If two different outputs are being displayed from the respective method calls, this implies that there must now be two different methods with the same name in the module.  Am I correct about that?

**Related Question:** out of curiosity, I tried the following code, but it didn't produce the same results:

```
module Sprocket
  def create
    "Sprocket"
  end

  module_function 

  def create
    "Sprocket 2.0"
  end
end

class SprocketFactory
  include Sprocket

  def make
    create
  end
end

p Sprocket.create             #=> "Sprocket 2.0"
p SprocketFactory.new.make    #=> "Sprocket 2.0"
```

Therefore, what would the API example code look like if the two `one` methods had been defined at the same time (instead of re-opening the module, as was done in the docs)?  Or is such a thing not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what would the API example code look like if the two `one` methods had been defined at the same time

```
module Sprocket
  def create
    "Sprocket"
  end

  module_function :create

  def create
    "Sprocket 2.0"
  end
end
```

You should imagine a timeline that is not revertable.

The first example (with `one`s): introduces an instance method `one`, declares it to be a module method, introduces new instance method `one`. The module method remains unchanged.

Your code with `create`: introduces an instance method `create`, introduces new “dual” scope for everything declared below with `module_function`, both introduces new module method and redeclares the instance method.

The code above: introduces an instance method, declares it to be a module method, introduces new instance method.